# Xamarin Forms - Bind a whole PageLayout created dynamically inside CarouselView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm having issues with rather simple operation, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I am looking to incorporate 7 pages into one CarouselView. The idea is to have 7 completeley different layouts, so I cannot use ItemTemplate (simply I'll have to do way too many operations with them to get it to work). Now I have an idea to use DataTemplate or return a build ContentPage and populate list that way, then display it inside my CarouselView. I have created a ViewModel creating the proper stacklayout, but I can't bind it to be displayed in xaml. I would be thankful for any guidance!

Comment: use a ContentView, not a ContentPage

Comment: Try [TabView](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/501)?

Comment: Please show us some code of what you've tried so far. Too be of any help we need more insights, it's better to post more information than is needed.

Comment: Hey! Thanks to y'all for giving me ideas, I ended up creating a DataTemplateSelector class and pushed basically any data template I wish by building it all in resource space of xaml page. It works very well and it seem to be optimized well-enough haha!

Answer (score 0):

to all who need to bind a whole stack layout/frame or content view inside a carousel view - it can only be done by building a datatemplate resource within your xaml layer, then combining it as an array of object, then setting the itemsource binding in your carousel view!